# How to force Polymer to use polyfill

Tags: polymer, polyfills

Since Polymer 1.0 release I start to get a different initialization order between Chrome and other browsers (Firefox, barebone WebKit). Although the 1.0 docs say ["there are no guarantees with regard to initialization timing"](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#initialization-order), in version 0.5 I didn't have such issue.

**index.html:**

```
<script src="components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="name-tag.html">
<body onload="console.log('body onload');">
  <name-tag></name-tag>
</body>
```

**name-tag.html:**

```
<link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="name-tag">
  <template></template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "name-tag",
      ready: function() {
        console.log("polymer ready");
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**Chrome 44:**

```
polymer ready
body onload
```

**Firefox 39, QWebView (Qt5.4, WebKit):**

```
body onload
polymer ready
```

What I have already tried:

- `window.WebComponents = {flags: {register: true, polyfill: true}};` ([register](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#initialization-order) used to be in `Polymer`)
- `window.Polymer.Settings = {useNativeShadow: false};`
- `attached` callback with `this.async()`

Answer (score 1):

`window.Polymer.dom = 'shadow'` forces Polymer to use the shadow DOM by default (either the polyfilled one if you used `webcomponents.js` or natively if you used `webcomponents-lite.js` instead).

Comment: _either the polyfilled one if you used webcomponents.js_ - the docs say the opposite: _'shadow' : Local DOM is rendered using shadow DOM where supported_. Meaning it will use native implementation **only** where supported. And this is what actually I get: Chrome renders with  `#shadow-root`, Firefox doesn't.